# Why passing datatable or dataset from controller to view is not recommended?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ado.net

I am new in MVC , I am trying to view data without using model, and passing datatable to view, I am able to achive this but when searched for this thing many people saying it not good prctice.
So I would like to know reason behind this. if anyone knows please share.

Comment: One of the basic concept of MVC itself is Model. You are deviating from the basic concept that is why everyone says it is not recommended.
Still you can pass datatable/dataset to view - but not a good way to do it.

Comment: You *are* using a model, even when its type is DataTable. Your Model class is the DataTable. That class is a lot harder to use in the view than another one with explicit properties and collections. You can't pass eg titles and messages, you are restricted to only a single collection of untyped data, you don't get intellisense. Why do you want to use a DataTable in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

there are a number of reasons for this, the most obvious being that in MVC good practice is to send to the view the data it needs, preferably already formatted, and nothing more. Datatables will contain more information then the view needs and the data won't be in the right format for the view.

When your data changes, your view will need to change to accommodate that and that's never a good thing. You're better off dealing with such changes in one place, in the back-end. Multiple views might use that code, so you're killing multiple birds with one stone if you apply proper separation of concerns.

Also, if you prepare your view-models in the back-end, you can test your code and will catch bugs quickly and early in your development process which, when done right, leads to better quality code. You can then hook up a proper CI/CD pipeline and automate all this, thus making your life a lot easier.

If you have a bunch of razor code on the front-end, errors there will not be visible until you look at the view directly which is never a good thing. You may not catch certain types of issues until you manually test each view.